# Centos VFS cannot open root device

Tags: centos, grub2, vfs

Yesterday I did a kernel update on a virtual machine. When I restarted the machine unfortunately I got the error `Kernel panic - not syncing VFS`

After some searching I found out I should go to GRUB and just select the old kernel and everything would be fine.

Wel I selected the old kernel but came to the following error;
`VFS: Cannot open root device "mapper/vg_cpanel-lv_root`

[image: Error trace]

So after some digging I found, [this question somewhere else](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/gentoo-linux/94418-error-vfs-cannot-open-root-device-unknown-block-0-0-a.html).
I went to rescue mode and do `vim /boot/grub/device.map` and 1 line appears
`(fd0) /dev/fd0` (nothing more).

I did a fdisk -l;
[image]

But there ends the train for me, unfortunately.
Following are 2 screen shots of my grub command;

[image: All commands]
[image: kernel command]

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I did "solve" it. Still don't know how.

I contacted a system friend of mine which pointed me to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0). I followed it but did not got past the second command.

I reset the system and somehow we got a third option in the GRUB which did work (magic) so now the system is running again.

So boys and girls don't forget to backup your stuff